# How to get a nested array into rowData

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ag-grid

I'm new to Angular and JS in general so please be gentle. I have an Angular 5 service that fetches JSON structured like this:

```
result: {
 objects: [
 {object1},
 {object2}.....
```

The JSON is then stored in a variable in my grid-component.ts as an object:

```
getVehicles() {
this._vehicleService.getVehicles().subscribe(
  data => { this.vehicles = data },
  err => console.error(err),
  () => console.log('done loading vehicles')
);
```

I'm trying to get the array portion of my result, ***objects[]***, into rowData without any luck. I've tried several approaches; iterating over objects and push to rowData.

```
for (let vehicle of this.vehicles.result.objects) {
   this.gridOptions.rowData.push(vehicle);
```

And just assigning ***objects[]*** to rowData but nothing seems to work. The issue seems to be with my expression;

```
this.vehicles.result.objects;
```

Everything past vehicle Angular says in undefined. The weird thing is that if I use string interpolation in my template I can use *ngFor to create a list if vehicleIds using the same expression, although the console still complains about undefined properties  ;

```
<ul>
<li *ngFor="let vehicle of vehicles.result.objects">
  {{ vehicle.vehicleId }}
</li>
```

Clearly, there's something fundamental I'm missing here. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you try to `console.log(this.vehicles.result.object)` ?

Comment: That was my first debugging strategy. Here's the console error:
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'object' of undefined
    at SafeSubscriber.eval [as _complete] (my-grid-application.component.ts:69)

Comment: this.vehicles.result.object should be this.vehicles.result.objects;

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo in my post. I got it right in my code. Fixed in post now

Comment: Please share result of the console.log(this.vehicles)

Comment: [object Object]   By the way Jibin was right and I was wrong. I did have a typo in my code. My console.log was object instead of objects. Once fixed can log this.vehicle.result. objects. Still can't get in rowData

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is with your `vehicles` object, initially it's not defined when component is being rendered. add `?` to overcome this problem.

```
<ul>
<li *ngFor="let vehicle of vehicles?.result.objects">
  {{ vehicle.vehicleId }}
</li>
```

Other possible way to use `async` pipe to solve this problem. You can find documentation related to `async` pipe [here](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe)

Comment: Thank you! I can fix my problem by setting the rowData in the template like this:    [rowData]="vehicles?.result.objects"> That accomplishes what I need but I still don't understand why I can't set rowData in my TS?

Comment: your row Data is defined like rowData:any[]=[]? You must inizialite your array as an empty array before you make a push